# R find difference between 2 year-week objects

Tags: r, datediff, strftime

I have 2 objects that are year-week#.  I'd like to find the difference between the 2 in weeks.

```
dd1 <- data.frame(date1 = as.Date('2015-01-01') + 1:31
                    , date2 = as.Date('2016-03-01') + 1:31
                    )
dd1$wk1 <- strftime(dd1$date1, format = '%Y-%W')
dd1$wk2 <- strftime(dd1$date2, format = '%Y-%W')

dd1$week_diff <- difftime(dd1$wk1, dd1$wk2)

Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Any suggestions?

NOTE: I can't use the original date as my data doesn't include them due to aggregation so it has to be a difference between the year_week#'s.

Comment: After you use `strftime` you don've have "year-week" objects, you have strings.

Answer (score 4):

Calculate the differences in weeks directly on `date1` and `date2` without converting it to character.

```
dd1$week_diff <- difftime(dd1$date1, dd1$date2, units = "weeks")

head(dd1)
       date1      date2       week_diff
1 2015-01-02 2016-03-02 -60.71429 weeks
2 2015-01-03 2016-03-03 -60.71429 weeks
3 2015-01-04 2016-03-04 -60.71429 weeks
4 2015-01-05 2016-03-05 -60.71429 weeks
5 2015-01-06 2016-03-06 -60.71429 weeks
6 2015-01-07 2016-03-07 -60.71429 weeks
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(lubridate)
dd1$date1 <- ymd(dd1$date1)
dd1$date2 <- ymd(dd1$date2)
interval_p = interval(dd1$date1, dd1$date2)
weeks = interval_p %/% weeks(1)
```